# Validate Coordinate entry using RegEx

Tags: regex, silverlight

I was wondering if anybody could help with some RegEx validating.
I have a text box where a user is to input a set of XY coordinates e.g. 123.345, 543.123
I can use the following bit of RegEx to check for a single X or Y coordinate.
`var pattern = "^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$";`  Allows only numbers and 1 decimal point to be entered.

But I can't figure out how to allow the user to enter a single whitespace and/or a comma after the X coordinate and then continue to enter the Y coordinate.

I know this would be easier with two different textboxes but because of the application and UI requirements I cannot add a second text box for the Y coordinate.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

> ^\d+(?:.\d+)?,\s\d+(?:.\d+)$

**Explanation :**

```
(1)    ^                 => Beginning of input
(2)    \d+(?:\.\d+)?     => Allow one or more digits followed optionally by a dot and one or more digits
(3)    ,\s               => Expect a comma and a single whitespace
(4)    \d+(?:\.\d+)      => See (1)
(5)    $                 => End of input
```

**Nota :**
If you expect only a single space change `,\s` into `,[ ]`.

Comment: `[ ]` is the same as just ` `. You can use this site to automatically explain your expressions: http://regex101.com/r/oW2hE3

Comment: Hi Stephen thanks for the really quick reply. 
the \d character is giving me an "Unrecognized escape sequence" error in SilverLight so you know of a way to avoid this?

Comment: Instead of writing `\d`, type `\\d`. If this still doesn't work change all `\d` occurences with `[0-9]`. HTH